# Equivalent of "defined" in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, utilities

I need a function that takes the name of a symbol as a string and returns whether that symbol is already defined.  The function `ValueQ` is close but it returns False for function names. Also, it takes symbols rather than strings.

Examples:

```
defined["N"] --> True (predefined function N)
defined["x"] --> False
x = 7;
defined["x"] --> True (x is now defined)
defined["7"] --> True (7 is a number)
f[x_] := 2x
defined["f"] --> True (f has DownValues)
g[x_][y_] := x+y
defined["g"] --> True (g has SubValues)
```

PS: Thanks to Pillsy for pointing out the need to check for both DownValues and SubValues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cobbled this together, which seems to work:

```
defined[s_] := ToExpression["ValueQ[" <> s <> "]"] || 
               Head@ToExpression[s] =!= Symbol || 
               ToExpression["Attributes[" <> s <> "]"] =!= {} ||
               ToExpression["DownValues[" <> s <> "]"] =!= {} ||
               ToExpression["SubValues[" <> s <> "]"] =!= {}
```

Hopefully there's a prettier solution.

PS: Thanks to Pillsy for pointing out the need to check for both DownValues and SubValues.

Comment: if I want to be dynamic, how can I convert Cos to "Cos"?

Answer (score 2):

I think Names should do the trick:

> Names["string"] gives a list of the
>   names of symbols which match the
>   string.

If Names["foo"] returns {}, then there should be no definitions for foo, otherwise it should return {"foo"}.
So your function 'defined' might be done as:

```
defined[str_] := Names[str] != {}
```

For symbols at least, because this doesn't work for "7", since 7 is not a symbol. You could handle this case seperately, for instance with NumberQ.

Also, you can use Symbol to make a symbol out of a string (useful for automatically generating symbols) and Definition to check the definitions of a symbol.

> Symbol["name"] refers to a symbol with
>   the specified name.
>
> Definition[symbol] prints as the
>   definitions given for a symbol.

**EDIT**: Better than looking at what Names returns, NameQ["name"] tells you if a given name exists. Still doesn't tell you if the symbol has an explicit definition though, just that it has been mentioned.

Comment: Oh, nice!  It fails for Names["7"] though.  Also, if you so much as mention a symbol x then Names["x"] will indicate it's defined even if it actually has no definition.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure if there is any way to know if a symbol has an explicit definition or it was only mentioned. Definition[foo] tells you this, but can't be used automatically I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DownValues` to see if you have "functions" associated with a symbol. This will work for definitions like

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
```

or

```
g[3] = 72 * a;
```

It won't work for exotic things like

```
h[a_][b] = "gribble";
```

but most people won't think of that as defining a function anyway. If you want to check for the existence of a function definition, you need to convert the name to an expression (and make sure it's wrapped in `Hold` when you do!). Here's a reasonably robust function that checks for both `DownValues` and `SubValues`:

```
functionNameQ[name_String] := 
    With[{ hSymbol = ToExpression[name, InputForm, Hold] },
        MatchQ[hSymbol, Hold[_Symbol]] &&
            ((DownValues @@ hName) =!= {} || (SubValues @@ hName) =!= {})];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
defined[str_] := Not[ToString[FullDefinition[str]] === ""]
```

Comment: This solution has side effects, it will evaluate functions. e.g. `f[x_] := Print[x]`, `defined[f["Hello"]]`. Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/58370).

Comment: @Rohit: That's an issue with the Halting Problem, not with my solution. Suppose you have f[x_] := Modue[{}, If[veryComplicatedConditionWhichNobodyKnowsWillEvenFinishComputingBeforeEternityCome, Sin, somethingUndefined], and you want to know if f[someX] is defined, then you want to know if the result is Sin or somethingUndefined, and if you can do that (in general) without actually calling veryComplicatedConditionWhichNobodyKnowsWillEvenFinishComputingBeforeEternityCome, then you can solve the Halting Problem.